# How to replace start and ending quote in a Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database where I want to fetch some data with an `IN` clause. But I am having error for the start and ending quote in the syntax. I don't know how to remove it. I have googled and tried replace, trim but no luck.

My current query that is giving error:

```
SELECT CARE_TOPIC_ID, CARE_TOPIC_NAME, CREATED_BY, HISTORY_OF_ILLNESS,
  ASSESSMENT, PLAN FROM CARE_TOPIC_TEMPLATES 
WHERE CARE_TOPIC_ID in ('1,2,3') ;
```

The required query should be:

```
SELECT CARE_TOPIC_ID, CARE_TOPIC_NAME, CREATED_BY, HISTORY_OF_ILLNESS,
  ASSESSMENT, PLAN FROM CARE_TOPIC_TEMPLATES 
WHERE CARE_TOPIC_ID in (1,2,3) ;
```

Comment: So you're passing a single string - which is coming from where? - and you're asking how to split it up so the numbers are matched by the `in`? Presumably you are getting an ORA-01722 from the implicit conversion of that string to a number, but it's better to tell us what actually happens, and give more context.

Comment: what is your error? The first query doesn't seem logically correct, but I wouldn't expect an error.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22075001/266304), depending on how you're executing the query and where the list of numbers is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of CARE_TOPIC_ID is text, the correct usage is:

```
  SELECT CARE_TOPIC_ID, CARE_TOPIC_NAME, CREATED_BY, HISTORY_OF_ILLNESS, ASSESSMENT, PLAN FROM CARE_TOPIC_TEMPLATES WHERE CARE_TOPIC_ID in ('1','2','3') ;
```

Or else if it is numeric, then:

```
  SELECT CARE_TOPIC_ID, CARE_TOPIC_NAME, CREATED_BY, HISTORY_OF_ILLNESS, ASSESSMENT, PLAN FROM CARE_TOPIC_TEMPLATES WHERE CARE_TOPIC_ID in (1,2,3) ;
```

Comment: You don't understand. it is integer. I know it should be 1,2,3. But I am sending from application '1,2,3'. The question was how to remove starting and ending quote(') from it.

Comment: @SumonBappi - the quotes are part of the string literal, not the actual value; removing them doesn't really mean anything, you're still left with a string, and it still can't be converted to a number or a list of numbers. Please edit the question to explain how you're running the query and passing the string from your application. Did you look at the old question I linked to as a possible duplicate?